# Missing template processor after updating ember-cli addon

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'm getting the following error from terminal when updating a private ember-cli addon:

`➜  fly-blankslate git:(chore-ember-110) ember server --port=4300
version: 0.2.0-beta.1
Missing template processor
Error: Missing template processor
    at module.exports.preprocessTemplates (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/preprocessors.js:149:11)
    at Class.Addon.compileTemplates (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:434:12)
    at Class.Addon.compileAddon (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:456:28)
    at Class.Addon.treeForAddon (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:382:24)
    at Class._treeFor (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:282:31)
    at Class.treeFor (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:253:19)
    at EmberAddon.<anonymous> (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:307:20)
    at Array.map (native)
    at EmberAddon.EmberApp.addonTreesFor (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:305:30)
    at EmberAddon._addonTree (/Users/alvincrespo/workspace/fly-blankslate/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:597:38)
➜  fly-blankslate git:(chore-ember-110)`

I ran `ember init` inside the addon and updated the bower.json and package.json:

**package.json**:

`{
  "name": "fly-blankslate",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "The default blueprint for ember-cli addons.",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.4",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.8",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ember-addon"
  ],
  "ember-addon": {
    "configPath": "tests/dummy/config"
  }
}`

**bower.json**:

`{
  "name": "fly-blankslate",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.10.0",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.11",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.2.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "fly-css-framework": "git@github.com:customerio/fly-css-framework.git"
  }
}`

Any ideas? I'm also seeing this when creating a new addon:

https://github.com/alvincrespo/test-templates

Answer (score 3):

You need to install ember-cli-htmlbars as a dependency in your addon. Go into the addon directory and type the following:

```
npm install --save ember-cli-htmlbars
```

Alternatively, you can open `package.json`, find the `ember-cli-htmlbars` dependency under `devDependencies` and **copy** it to be under `dependencies` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In **Ember 1.10** upwards, I think the template processor you need might is: **ember-template-compiler.js**.

See this blog post: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html

Move your code to jsbin and add this and see if it runs.

```
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/preprocessors.js` file in your project folder .
Now replace `broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler` with `ember-cli-htmlbars`

You have do this again if you somehow delete `/node_modules/ember-cli` folder.

Hope it helps.